# Count in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote the following query to try and count the number of flights that go to a specific city, but I cant make it work

```
SELECT F.FLI_ID, A.AIRPORT_ID, C.CITY_ID 
FROM FLIGHT F INNER JOIN (AIRPORT A INNER JOIN CITY C ON A.CITY_ID = C.CITY_ID)
ON F.ARRV_AIRPORT = A.AIRPORT_ID
WHERE C.CITY_ID = 1000
GROUP BY F.FLI_ID, A.AIRPORT_ID, C.CITY_ID;
```

**Yields**

```
    FLI_ID AIRPORT_ID    CITY_ID
---------- ---------- ----------
        19          1       1000
        11          1       1000
```

*Should Yield*

```
NO.FLIGHTS AIRPORT_ID    CITY_ID
---------- ---------- ----------
        2          1       1000
```

**I have tried the following query**

```
SELECT COUNT(F.FLI_ID) AS NO_FLIGHTS, A.AIRPORT_ID, C.CITY_ID 
FROM FLIGHT F INNER JOIN (AIRPORT A INNER JOIN CITY C ON A.CITY_ID = C.CITY_ID)
ON F.ARRV_AIRPORT = A.AIRPORT_ID
WHERE C.CITY_ID = 1000
GROUP BY F.FLI_ID, A.AIRPORT_ID, C.CITY_ID;
```

AND i get the following result

NO_FLIGHTS AIRPORT_ID    CITY_ID

---

```
     1          1       1000
     1          1       1000
```

Comment: You have no `COUNT()` in your `SELECT` list, and remove `F.FLI_ID` from both `SELECT`,`GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't group by the same value that you're trying to count... that's why you end up with a count of one for each row.

Change your `GROUP BY` from:

```
GROUP BY F.FLI_ID, A.AIRPORT_ID, C.CITY_ID;
```

To:

```
GROUP BY A.AIRPORT_ID, C.CITY_ID;
```

Which gives you the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(F.FLI_ID) AS NO_FLIGHTS, A.AIRPORT_ID, C.CITY_ID 
FROM FLIGHT F INNER JOIN (AIRPORT A INNER JOIN CITY C ON A.CITY_ID = C.CITY_ID)
ON F.ARRV_AIRPORT = A.AIRPORT_ID
WHERE C.CITY_ID = 1000
GROUP BY A.AIRPORT_ID, C.CITY_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i didnt know that i had to get rid of the key that is being counted in the group

Answer (score 3):

Remove `FLI_ID` from the `GROUP BY`. By leaving it in, you are forcing the count to aggregate the number of flights per `FLI_ID`, which will always be 1, so you'll get a row for each flight id.

```
SELECT COUNT(F.FLI_ID) AS NO_FLIGHTS, A.AIRPORT_ID, C.CITY_ID 
FROM FLIGHT F INNER JOIN (AIRPORT A INNER JOIN CITY C ON A.CITY_ID = C.CITY_ID)
ON F.ARRV_AIRPORT = A.AIRPORT_ID
WHERE C.CITY_ID = 1000
GROUP BY A.AIRPORT_ID, C.CITY_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT count(1) as NUM_FLIGHTS, A.AIRPORT_ID, C.CITY_ID 
FROM FLIGHT F INNER JOIN (AIRPORT A INNER JOIN CITY C ON A.CITY_ID = C.CITY_ID)
ON F.ARRV_AIRPORT = A.AIRPORT_ID
WHERE C.CITY_ID = 1000
GROUP BY A.AIRPORT_ID, C.CITY_ID;
```